# Describe the set of all $z$ such that $Im(z+5)=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Describe the set of all $z$ such that $Im(z+5)=0$. So here is what I have so far.

$$ z = a+bi $$
$$ Im(z+5) = Im(a+bi+5)= b$$
Now does this imply that $b=0$ because if we have $$Im(z+5)=b$$ and $$Im(z+5)=0$$, then $b$ must be zero? I feel as if I'm doing this wrong somehow or this is too easy?

Comment: Adding a real number to a complex number won't change its imaginary part.

Comment: It is too easy!

Comment: The back of my book describes the set as the "real axis" so I am indeed right that this just means that the imaginary part of our equation is zero, thus it just gives the real axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you're doing this right. In fact it's easy to prove that $Im(a+b)=Im(a)+Im(b)$ thus $0=Im(z+5)=Im(z)$ so $z\in\mathbb{R}$ since $z=Re(z)+iIm(z)=Re(z)\in\mathbb{R}$.

Now $\forall z\in\mathbb{R},\,Im(z+5)=Im(z)=0$ so $\left\{z\in\mathbb{C},\,Im(z+5)=0\right\}=\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Wonderful, so I was indeed correct by saying that $b=0$ by the assumption that $Im(z+5)=0$ and thus this gives the real axis or all real numbers.

Comment: Yes! Absolutely yes!